# Getting hWnd for CommandButton of UserForm

Tags: winapi

I'm using Excel(2003) VBA. I have "UserForm1" with a command button, "bHide". I'm using FindWindow to get the hwnd for UserForm1. With that I'm successfully changing the window style (removing the form border). I also want to modify "bHide" but I need to get its handle. 
What's the best way to get the handle for "bHide"? Thanks.

Comment: Alex K. wrote: "MS Forms controls like CommandButtons are not windows at all, they are "Windowless controls" i.e they 
are drawn by the MS Forms Runtime onto the userform surface as purely graphical abstractions, so no HWND."

So, options...
1. Create a window and use it as a button
2. Use API to change the "style" of the button (which has no border property)?

Comment: Bill Manville, MVP, posted this a while back in response to another question: "Instead of an ActiveX command button, why not use an object from the Drawing toolbar which you can format as you wish and to which you can add text and attach a macro?" This is a good idea but is (obviously) outside the API. A label control has a click event and border control so it's a good workaround.